# c# REGEX parse content with new line included in group

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to evaluate, using c#, the content of a string following this pattern (number and description are separated by a tab - header is not part of the text, only here for sake of explanation ):

```
#   description
1   first item
2   second item on two or
    more lines of text
3   third item
```

and I would like to get a list of match where there's a group for the number and and a group for the description.  I've almost achieved it with the following regex :

```
(?'number'\d+)(?:\t)(?'description'.+)
```

which gave me 3 matches but the text of the second match on the new line is always discarded.  Can't find how to include the text on multiples lines within the *description* group.

Comment: Isn't it loads easier to replace any line breaks followed by a tab character with a single space as preprocessing step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert that what follows the `.*` is not a newline and 1+ digits followed by a tab.

Repeat 0+ times matching the whole line to keep it in the `description` group.

```
(?'number'\d+)\t(?'description'.+(?:\n(?!\d+\t).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?'number'\d+)` Match 1+ digits in group `number`
- `\t` Match a tab
- `(?'description'` Named capturing group `description`

  - `.+` Match any char except a newline
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\n(?!\d+\t).*` Match newline and assert what follows is not 1+ digits and a tab
  - `)*`  Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close group description

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%27number%27%5cd%2b%29%5ct%28%3f%27description%27.%2b%28%3f%3a%5cn%28%3f!%5cd%2b%5ct%29.*%29*%29&i=%23%09description%0d%0a1%09first+item%0d%0a2%09second+item+on+two+or%0d%0a%09more+lines+of+text%0d%0a3%09third+item)

Comment: Thank you SO much.  This worked like a charm!  Even added optional '\n' next to the number : @"(?'number'\d+(?:\n?)+)\t(?'description'.+(?:\n(?!\d+\t).*)*)";

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(?'number'\d+)\t(?'description'.+?)(?=^\d|\Z)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ENT3lq/2)

Comment: sorry but as soon as there's digit in the description, stop working ...

Comment: @CarlVerret, I've edited the post to include the fix.